# JavaFX changing a label in parent FXML

Tags: javafx-8

- Parent Files: FXML-A & Controller-A
- Child Files: FXML-B & Controller-B

I have above hierarchy structure where FXML-B is on top of FXML-A, loaded from the Controller-A using "parent_stackPane.***getChildren().setAll***(child_fxmlLoader_load)" kind of a way. So FXML-A is the parent of FXML-B.

Is there anyway that I can change the text of the label in parent FXML-A from the child Controller-B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `StringProperty` in `ControllerB`:

```
public class ControllerB {

    private StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text ;
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    // other code as before ...

}
```

When you load the second fxml in `ControllerA`, bind the text of the label to the `textProperty`:

```
public class ControllerA {

    @FXML
    private Label label ;

    @FXML
    private StackPane parentStackPane ;

    @FXML
    private void someHandlerMethod() throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FxmlFileB.fxml"));
        Parent rootB = loader.load();
        ControllerB controllerB = loader.getController();
        label.textProperty().unbind();
        label.textProperty().bind(controllerB.textProperty());
        parentStackPane.getChildren().setAll(rootB);
    }

    // other code as before...
}
```

Now when you call `setText(...)` in `ControllerB`, it will update the text in the label.